# How can I insert multiple UITableViewCells so that they appear behind existing cells and their individual heights don't change?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to insert multiple `UITableViewCells` with an animation to my `UITableView`. Unfortunately, their heights animate from 0 to their correct height when I'm using `UITableView.RowAnimation.top`:

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]], with: .top)
```

**Result:**

[image: incorrect UITableView animation]

This would be my desired result:

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this result, put the insertion code inside a `UIView.animate` block:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: <index paths>, with: .none)
}
```

If the bottom of the newly inserted cell group is visible behind the already present cells, use a fade-in animation or a mask to hide parts of the animation.

---

Interestingly, there's no need for a `UIView.animate` group if you're *deleting* rows:

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]], with: .bottom)
```

> Note: this does not work well when cell separators are enabled, so I'd suggest disabling them and creating a custom view or layer if you really need them.

**Result:**

[image: result of tableView.deleteRows with UITableView.RowAnimation.bottom]